# querySelectorAll dosen't work with Angular but works in console

Tags: angular, document, selectors-api, queryselector

I have a div which contains some checkboxes, I want to access these check boxes using  `querySelectorAll` but it seems not works inside Angular although it works in the console.

```
@Component({
  selector: "formly-field-categories-helper",
  template: `
    <div [innerHTML]="categories"></div>
  `
})



ngOnInit() { 
 let inputs = '<input type="checkboxes" name="group" /> test`
 this.categories = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(inputs); 
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  //alerts 0 
  alert(document.querySelectorAll('[name="groups"]').length);
}
```

but when I open the cosole and run `document.querySelectorAll('[name="groups"]').length` it gives me 192 (not 0)

you can check the full code from here
https://github.com/goblins-tech/almogtama3/blob/master/src/app/content/editor.ts#L248

**note**
using `setTimeout` will solve the issue, but I don't to use it. I want to run the code only after the DOM has been completely created.

```
setTimeout(() => {
      alert(document.querySelectorAll('[name="groups"]').length);
    }, 5000);
```

**note** `ngAfterViewChecked` runs multiple times, so I avoid using it.

in the next step I will replace `document.querySelectorAll` with `nativeElement.querySelectorAll`

Answer (score 0):

Good day!

Have you tried smth like this?

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    alert(document.querySelectorAll('[name="groups"]').length);
  });
}
```

Comment: worked, but I want another solution without setTimeout, I want to run the code only when the DOM completed